# iOS React Native TransformError

Tags: ios, react-native

Using this configuration :

> OX S 10.11.3
>      npm 3.5.2
>      node 5.1.0
>      Xcode 7.2.1
>      React Native 0.1.10

I have the following error:

```
407/408Error while persisting cache: TransformError: /Users/apple/Desktop/HelloReactNative/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/lib/index.js: [BABEL] /Users/apple/Desktop/HelloReactNative/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/lib/index.js: Unknown option: /Users/apple/Desktop/HelloReactNative/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/.babelrc.stage
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to resolve this?Thx.

Comment: OK, you need to edit the question and add a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .babelrc file to your project with the following :

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "compact": true,
  "comments": false,
  "plugins": [],
  "presets": ["stage-0", "react", "react-native"],
  "sourceMaps": false,
}
```

and install dev-dependencies with `npm i --save-dev <pacakge-name>` and the following development dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.4.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13"
}
```

**Edit**

Following the link provided by @S.Yeah, it looks like the error came from the .babelrc file in the `react-deep-force-update` package. Deleting that file should do the trick :

```
cd node_modules/react-deep-force-update && rm -rf .babelrc
```

Comment: How to operate?Use console?

Comment: To add the dev-dependencies, you can write in console: `npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react` for example

Comment: Sorry,still don't understand.  :(